# jasmine-browser-runner reports: Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am using Jasmine for unit testing of javascript/typescript server size code. It works as expected for command prompt based testing. When I used jasmine-browser-runner (>npx jasmine-browser-runner) and start the browser, I get:

```
0 specs, 0 failures, randomized with seed 00949
Error during loading: Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined in http://localhost:8888/__spec__/test.spec.js line 2
```

This is the content of most simple test.spec.ts (compiled from typescript to js):

```
import "jasmine";
describe("B suite", function () {
  it("contains spec with an expectation", function () {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

js:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
require("jasmine");
describe("B suite", function () {
    it("contains spec with an expectation", function () {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});

//# sourceMappingURL=test.spec.js.map
```

in tsconfig.json:

```
"target": "ES2015"
 "module": "commonjs"
```

Any idea?
br